# How to fix 'Error Creating Bean' (BeanCreationException) in Maven Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-bean, beancreationexception

I am creating a User Registration System using Maven & Java Spring Boot. While I am able to get the project to successfully build, the application cannot start with the following error trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-04-07T18:10:43.674-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.Spring.Test.SpringDevApplication     : Starting SpringDevApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 23400 (C:\temp\SpringDev\target\classes started by b.hasseman in C:\temp\SpringDev)
2023-04-07T18:10:43.679-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.Spring.Test.SpringDevApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-07T18:10:43.725-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-04-07T18:10:43.725-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-04-07T18:10:44.098-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-07T18:10:44.136-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-07T18:10:44.444-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jpaConfig' of type [com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-04-07T18:10:44.912-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-04-07T18:10:44.922-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-07T18:10:44.922-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-04-07T18:10:45.002-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-07T18:10:45.004-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1276 ms
2023-04-07T18:10:45.085-04:00  WARN 23400 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/registration/Spring/Test/JpaConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' threw exception with message: null
2023-04-07T18:10:45.088-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-04-07T18:10:45.103-04:00  INFO 23400 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-07T18:10:45.122-04:00 ERROR 23400 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/registration/Spring/Test/JpaConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' threw exception with message: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.SpringDevApplication.main(SpringDevApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' threw exception with message: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1301) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:229) ~[na:na]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig.additionalProperties(JpaConfig.java:91) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig.mysqlEntityManagerFactory(JpaConfig.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$mysqlEntityManagerFactory$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.mysqlEntityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

[ [1;34mINFO [m]  [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------ [m
[ [1;34mINFO [m]  [1;32mBUILD SUCCESS [m
[ [1;34mINFO [m]  [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------ [m
[ [1;34mINFO [m] Total time:  3.747 s
[ [1;34mINFO [m] Finished at: 2023-04-07T18:10:45-04:00
[ [1;34mINFO [m]  [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my JpaConfig.java:

```
package com.registration.Spring.Test;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.registration.Spring.Test",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public class JpaConfig {
    @Autowired
    private final Environment env;
    
    public JpaConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String [] { "com.registration.Spring.Test" });
        
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        
        return em;
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mysqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", env.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));
        return properties;
    }
    
    
}
```

This is my application.properties (with the actual username and password changed):

```
# data source configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_registration_system
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

# JPA configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    <!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringDev</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried changing the driver class, changing between jakarta and javax, and using different qualifier annotations.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at com.registration.Spring.Test.JpaConfig.additionalProperties(JpaConfig.java:91) ~[classes/:na]

From above error message, we are able to indicate that because of line 91, showing NullPointerException, thus lead to app startup failed.

I have checked your application.properties. With below code to load property value. the key of property must be same as value in source code.
Java code:
env.getProperty("**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**")

application.properties file

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto**=update
here should be **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**=update

and the rest should follow same.